# no detected operating system

Tags: dual-boot, 13.10

i am trying to install Ubuntu alongside Windows8 but while trying to do so it was showing as"This computer currently has no detected operating system"
can i know whats wrong with this??
please help me in clearing out this problem.
thanks in advance

Comment: did you post the screenshot of gparted?